# Zero validation loss and validation accuracy at classification problem

Tags: keras, classification

I'm running a multiclass classification problem using the below resnet model:

```
resnet = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50( 
    include_top=False ,
    weights='imagenet' ,
    input_shape=(96, 96, 3) ,
    pooling="avg"
)
for layer in resnet.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

model_resnet = tf.keras.Sequential()
model_resnet.add(resnet)
model_resnet.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model_resnet.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax',name='output') ) 
model_resnet.compile( loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy" , optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)  ,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I also used a train and a test generator as below:
`train_generator=img_gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_dataset,x_col="file_loc",y_col='expr',target_size=(96, 96),batch_size=91,class_mode="raw")`
`test_generator=img_gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=test_dataset,x_col="file_loc",target_size=(96, 96),batch_size=93,y_col=None,shuffle=False,class_mode=None)`

when I am running the code below I get the wanted results and everything works fine

```
model_resnet.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN_resnet,
                    epochs=20
)
```

I wanted to compute the validation accuracy of every epoch so I wrote something like this

```
model_path = f"/content/weights" + "{val_accuracy:.4f}.hdf5"


checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    model_path,
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    save_best_only=True,
    mode='max',
    verbose=1
)

history = model_resnet.fit_generator(
                   train_generator,
                   epochs=5,
                   steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN_resnet,
                   validation_data=test_generator,
                   validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_TEST_resnet,
                   max_queue_size=1,
                   shuffle=True,
                   callbacks=[checkpoint],
                   verbose=1
                  )
```

The problem is that for every epoch the validation loss and validation accuracy remain zero even though the training loss and accuracy change. I ran this code for over 20 epochs and it doesn't change at all. I can't find what am I doing wrong since without this it works perfectly,does anyone have any idea?

```
Epoch 1: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.00000, saving model to /content/weights0.0000.hdf5
500/500 [==============================] - 30s 60ms/step - loss: 1.0213 - accuracy: 0.6546 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
500/500 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.9644 - accuracy: 0.6672
Epoch 2: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
500/500 [==============================] - 29s 58ms/step - loss: 0.9644 - accuracy: 0.6672 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

**Edit:** I didn't specify the test labels of the test dataset because I used to compute the accuracy score as below:

```
y_pred = model_resnet.predict(test_generator)
y_pred_max = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
y_true = test_dataset["expr"].to_numpy()
print("accuracy",accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred_max))
```

I changed the test_generator as below:
`test_generator=img_gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=test_dataset,x_col="file_loc",target_size=(96, 96),batch_size=93,y_col='expr',shuffle=False,class_mode=None)`

but nothing has changed, it still results in zero

Comment: Does your test set have labels? Notice how you are not specifying labels for your validation generator.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I didnt specify the labels because in the below article it says "y_col: None, if used for test_generator " https://vijayabhaskar96.medium.com/tutorial-on-keras-flow-from-dataframe-1fd4493d237c

Comment: Well that is wrong, I also asked if your test set has labels, accuracy needs labels, no labels, then accuracy is meaningless.

Comment: Yes it has test labels, I didnt specify them because I didn't need them before (see edit).I tried specifying them but the result is the same

Comment: You are not using the same generator configuration, class_mode has different values in train and test generators.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I was confused because at the link I wrote above it says "For Test generator: Set class mode to None, to return only the images." and since it didn't crash I thought it was correct. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dr.Snoopy said, the problems were that I didn't specify the test labels in these generator (which are required to compute accuracy) and I had different class modes in the generator,the correct was "raw" in both.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).